# Conflict between OpenLDAP's libldap and Oracle's occi library

Tags: linux, oracle, ldap, conflict, symbols

I'm writing a small tool to do some checks on the data from one Oracle database and on LDAP.
Thinking of performance I've decided to go with C/C++, therefore I'm using the open ldap library and the oracle occi library. Now putting together the wrappers for each library I noticed that functions from the ldap library fail if I link my program with the oracle library. Going further I see there are functions defined in the oracle library with the same name as they're defined in the openldap library.
Now I did not find much on web on this issue, some advise to link first with the ldap library but that doesn't do it, it doesn't fail on init() anymore but it doesn't go past connect().

I'm doing the developing on Linux (Ubuntu), and the libraries I use are all C.
Does anyone have any advice on this? There must be someone else that have had this issue.

Any thoughts are most welcomed.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless these functions are also API entry points you should be able to make it work by linking to both as shared libraries. Then each library will use its own version of the function and you don't get to see either version unless you call it yourself.

If the functions concerned are API entry points, i.e. LDAP APIs, there is something pretty odd going on.

Comment: I've build the ldap library as shared library and I'm linking against both as shared libraries. This is happening when I'm linking against the oracle's libclntsh, please see below:
`objdump -T libclntsh.so | grep " ldap_sasl_bind_s"
00fec288 g    DF text.unlikely 0000004c  Base        ldap_sasl_bind_s`

Comment: @seven That appears to indicate that the Oracle library already contains everything you need. Try using just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by specifying "-lldap -llber" in linking stage.

Ensure that you have specified oracle libray at the end in the linking stage. ldap has dependency with liblber.